# C++ SFML Compile errors sf::NonCopyable::NonCopyable(const sf::NonCopyable&) is private

Tags: c++, sfml

When I try to compile the following code:

SFMLSet.cpp:

```
#include "SFMLSet.h"

SFMLSet::SFMLSet(string texturePath)
{
    if(!texture.loadFromFile(texturePath)) {
        exit(1);
    }
    new (&app) sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(texture.getSize().x, texture.getSize().y), texturePath, sf::Style::None);
    new (&sprite) sf::Sprite(texture);
}
```

SFMLSet.h:

```
#ifndef SFMLSET_H
#define SFMLSET_H
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class SFMLSet {
    public:
        sf::RenderWindow app;
        sf::Texture texture;
        sf::Sprite sprite;

        sf::Vector2i grabbedOffset;
        bool grabbedWindow = false;

        SFMLSet (string texturePath);

        sf::Event event;
};


#endif // SFMLSET_H
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include "SFMLSet.h"


int main()
{
    bool isRunning=true;
    vector<SFMLSet> IMGS;
    IMGS.push_back (SFMLSet ("cb.bmp"));

    while (isRunning)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<IMGS.size();i++) {
        while (IMGS[i].app.pollEvent(IMGS[i].event))
        {
            if (IMGS[i].event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                IMGS[i].app.close();
                isRunning=false;
            }
             if (IMGS[i].event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && IMGS[i].event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
                        {
                                IMGS[i].app.close();
                                isRunning=false;
                        }
                        else if (IMGS[i].event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed)
                        {
                                if (IMGS[i].event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left)
                                {
                                        IMGS[i].grabbedOffset = IMGS[i].app.getPosition() - sf::Mouse::getPosition();
                                        IMGS[i].grabbedWindow = true;
                                }
                        }
                        else if (IMGS[i].event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased)
                        {
                                if (IMGS[i].event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left)
                                        IMGS[i].grabbedWindow = false;
                        }
                        else if (IMGS[i].event.type == sf::Event::MouseMoved)
                        {
                                if (IMGS[i].grabbedWindow&&(IMGS[i].grabbedOffset.x<-10&&IMGS[i].grabbedOffset.y<-10)&&(IMGS[i].grabbedOffset.x>-(IMGS[i].texture.getSize().x)+10&&IMGS[i].grabbedOffset.y>-(IMGS[i].texture.getSize().y)+10))
                                        IMGS[i].app.setPosition(sf::Mouse::getPosition() + IMGS[i].grabbedOffset);
                        }
        }

        IMGS[i].app.clear();

        IMGS[i].app.draw(IMGS[i].sprite);

        IMGS[i].app.display();
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I get some errors:

> SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/System/NonCopyable.hpp:67:5: error:
>   'sf::NonCopyable::NonCopyable(const sf::NonCopyable&)' is private
>
> SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/Window/Window.hpp:57:23: error: within this
>   context
>
> SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/System/NonCopyable.hpp:67:5: error: 'sf::NonCopyable::NonCopyable(const sf::NonCopyable&)' is private
>
> SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.hpp:51:25: error: within
>   this context
>
> SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/System/NonCopyable.hpp:79:18: error: 'sf::NonCopyable& sf::NonCopyable::operator=(const sf::NonCopyable&)'
>   is private
>
> SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/Window/Window.hpp:57:23: error:
>   within this context
>
> SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/System/NonCopyable.hpp:79:18: error: 'sf::NonCopyable& sf::NonCopyable::operator=(const sf::NonCopyable&)'
>   is private
>
> SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.hpp:51:25:
>   error: within this context

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't want to sound rude, but start by properly learning the bases of C++. For example, `new (&app) sf::RenderWindow(...` is **not** what you should be doing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read the [SFML tutorials](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3), and write programs like their examples.

The concrete problem here is that the copy constructor of `sf::RenderWindow` is private - usually it makes no sense to copy a window.

Unfortunately, you used `SFMLSet` in a `std::vector`. Vectors have to grow their size dynamically, and to implement this, they allocate a new bigger buffer, and copy their existing content to the new location - calling the copy constructor of `SFMLSet`, which in turn tries to call `sf::RenderWindow`s.

The best way to fix this is probably to remove `sf::RenderWindow` from IMGS, and keep it as a local variable in `main`, again, as in the tutorials. You probably didn't mean to open a new window for each image, right?

Comment: Can't you use `std::vector` with move-only types if you use `emplace_back` instead of `push_back`? Still, I agree that there's something wrong with the use of `sf::RenderWindow`: `app` should probably be a smart pointer to a window

Comment: sf::RenderWindow isn't movable - it declares a private copy constructor, but no move constructor. C++11 support is on their roadmap, but not yet implemented.

Comment: Then it's going to have to be dynamically allocated, I guess

Comment: It can be allocated on the stack, as the examples in the tutorial do too. It's ok as long as it isn't copied.

Comment: No, I did mean to open a new window for each image.

Comment: Then you have to make sure that your window's won't be copied, even when the vector is resized. One way to do it is to allocate them with `std::unique_ptr`s.

Answer (score 2):

That error message tells you that you are attempting to copy an instance of `sf::NonCopyable` somewhere. The compiler is saying that you are trying to call the copy-constructor of that class, but that copy constructor is defined privately and so cannot be accessed.

To fix it you need to work out what is causing the `sc::NonCopyable` instance to be copied, and change that code so there is no copy (possibly using a pointer).